# Error adding App Manifest to Teams Admin center

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am adding an app manifest to MS Teams admin center. Here is my manifest.Json.
In Teams Admin Center

1. Navigate to Manage Apps section
2. Click Upload new App and i select the zip file

I get the error : "Mgmt.AppCatalog.LOBApp.Upload.BadRequest.Error"
Any help is highly appreciated :-)

Manifest

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "XXXXXXXX-GUID",
  "packageName": "com.xx.pva.middleware123",
  "developer": {
    "name": "xx",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.xx.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.xx.com/Privacy-Policy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.xx.com/",
    "mpnId": "0000000"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "My Bot",
    "full": "My Bot"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "My Bot",
    "full": "Bot integrating all services"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#254b99",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "XXXXXXX-GUID. Same as id above",
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "*.botframework.com",
    "*.*.botframework.com",
    "login.microsoftonline.com",
    "powerva.microsoft.com",
    "*.consent.azure-apim.net",
    "*.azure-apim.net"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please validate your app package in Teams store app validation in Developer Portal and check what error you are getting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdjmV.png If there are no errors, please do share the manifest zip package, so that we can evaluate from our end once

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully tested your manifest, but immediately offhand I can see some issues:

1. your manifest version (1.1) is -very- old - if you don't need it so old, update to a newer one
2. You manifest Id and Bot Id should **NOT** be the same Id. One is for the "app manifest" in Teams, the other is the Azure Application ID for the Bot itself - you need to get that from Azure's Bot registration.
3. Offhand, I don't think you need -any- of those "validdomain" entries for a bot, they're mostly needed for other app types (like a Tab app)